# Keep powerline prompt on ssh

Tags: ssh, sshd, powerline

I have a powerline bash prompt in iterm2 on my MacOS client and I want to keep the prompt when I ssh into different servers.

I regularly ssh into: a local headless vm, a server for school assignments,  and a seedbox, and I'd rather not keep 4 different configurations synced, plus I can't install powerline on my school's server.

Is there some way to keep my prompt when I ssh to a different machine?

Comment: AFAIK you have to install it on the host server. If you have your own account on your school server, then you can (probably) just install powerline in the user home. I've done the same with zsh powerline.

Comment: Hmm I see. I'll poke around and see what I can do. Thanks!

Comment: Reading the [docs](https://github.com/riobard/bash-powerline), it looks like you just need to download, then source powerline, so no root access required. In terms of keeping your configs synced, I have a git server installed in my server, and just upload dotfiles. (Git servers are super easy to install. You just need ssh access and git installed, basically.)

Comment: I usually host my dots on github so I should have an easy enough time. Just wanted to make sure there wasn't an easier option. Thank you for the help.

Comment: No worries; good luck! Hopefully someone else might have an idea on how to use a centralised config.